# Using boost factory to produce products on demands C++

Tags: c++, boost, factory

What confused me is that I don't want to create a object with a pointer like 'Product_ptr productA', are there some other methods?  Another questions is that all my products use DoSomething(), but I also want to add different attributes to different products, how to achieve this?  Thanks for your suggestions!!

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "add different attributes to different products"?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) are your solution to lifetime management issues.

Comment: @sehe Hey, I am afraid that the pointer is not a good way for memory problems, actually, I should handle different back-ends, and DoSomething()here is like serialization, it will sent its attributes to other back-end, and it will get the reply, do unserialization, so I want use object, not pointers, because I can't image the address problem...Thank you

Comment: @Rost the attributes will be different for products, maybe productA needs two string members, but productB needs three int members...

Comment: What the problem with properties? Just add corresponding data members to `ConcreteProductA` and `ConcreteProductB`. Or you need them to be passed to product on construction?

Comment: I want to create the product with objedts, not a object's pointer Product_ptr productA, which is not safe @Rost

Comment: Why do you think pointers are not safe? Smart pointers _are_ safe.

Comment: @Rost Sorry for my explanation, the properties are some members of ConcreteProductB, but it is only in this product. When I want to use these members outside the class, I can't use pointers like productB->members, these members can be int or string, etc. Thanks

Comment: You always can hide pointers with reference: `ProductB& ref = *productB; ref.member1(); ref.member2();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you cannot avoid pointers in C++ when dealing with dynamically created objects. You have to manage and pass ownership for such objects which is naturally done with pointers, mainly smart pointers, of course.

Despite there are some ways to hide them, e.g. maintaining ownership of objects in some central point (factory) and pass them to consumers by reference. Such way has several drawbacks, e.g. consumer need explicitly release the object so the factory can destroy it and not waste resources. But if your objects are lightweight and their lifetime is the same as lifetime fo entire program or specific factory, this could be useful.

**Example:**

```
template <class Product>
class Factory
{
   // List elements are unaffected by insertion/deletion
   // Could be also container of smart pointers if objects need
   // to be created directly on heap
   std:list<Product> m_objects;

public:

   Product& CreateProduct()
   {
      m_objects.push_back(Product());
      return m_objects.back();
   } 

};

// Usage
Factory<MyProduct> factory;
MyProduct& prod = factory.CreateProduct();
...
```

This solution is possible, but has limitations, don't use it without real need.
Returning appropriate smart pointer from factory, e.g. `std::shared_ptr` is preferable because it gives you explicit semantics on object ownership and makes code more clear, maintanable and error-proof.